# Get the property in vbscropy to get the path

Tags: vbscript

Here is my code:

```
Option Explicit
Dim fso, s , i 

Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FilesystemObject")
MsgBox "1"
s = Session.Property("TARGETDIR")
MsgBox "2"
i = Session.Property ("INSTALLDIR")
MsgBox "3"
MsgBox s & "\CopyDuringInstallation.txt"

fso.CopyFile s & "\CopyDuringInstallation.txt", i
MsgBox "4"
```

I am having trouble with the varaible s. Which property should I use to make a universal path?
All i want to know is the property which can concatenate the path as shown in the code after msgbox 3.

Thank You

Comment: Yes, ASP is VBScript, but OP uses Session. In plain VBScript there is no such object.

Comment: Thank you Lanny.. one more thing i ma using this in install shield. And i want to concatenate the CopyDuringInstallation.txt file with the address stored in varable s. Is there any other property apart from TARGETDIR

Comment: I Changed the variable name but it dint make any difference to the execution. can you help as to how to join both the paths so that it can be used universally.

Comment: What do you mean with "used universally"? Is it that you want a UNC path? Or a URL? Or something else?

Comment: By universally i meant that if anybody else installs the program the variable s should give the file source address automatically.

Answer (score 0):

The `CopyFile` method requires that the second argument also specifies a file name:

```
fso.CopyFile s & "\CopyDuringInstallation.txt", i & "\CopyDuringInstallation.txt"
```

I would advise to use more descriptive variable names, like `targetDir` instead of `i`.

Comment: Consider using  `fso.BuildPath( s, "file.txt")` instead of `s & "\file.txt"`. The `BuildPath` method inserts an additional path separator between the existing path and the name, only if necessary.